# Multiple checkbox filtering in NGPrime data table in Angular 6

Tags: angularjs, primeng-datatable

I have ng prime data table in my page. there is one column with comma separated value but multiple checkbox filters are not working on it. It only works when there is only single value in table cell when comma separated value then it not works.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Instead of using ngPrime table, why don't you write your custom filter on every field?? This will work

Comment: Use for questions about AngularJS (1.x), the open-source JavaScript framework. Do NOT use this tag for Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the [angular] tag.

Comment: Can one custom filter works on every field or I have to create individual?